# jquery/templating get json item attribute

Tags: jquery

in my html page I have:

```
<script type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl" id="product_list_tmpl"> 
<label> 
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio${id}" value="${product_name}" >
    <label for="radio${id}"></label>                
</label>
</script>  
<div id='product_list_div'>
</div>
<script>
...
success : function(xhr){
var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xhr));
if(jsonData != null && jsonData.length) {
$.each(jsonData, function(index, item) {
var _options = {};
$("#product_list_tmpl").tmpl(item, _options).appendTo("#product_list_div");
...
</script>
```

The content of the jsonData:

```
[{"id":"1","product_name":"prod1","price":"885"}
{"id":"2","product_name":"prod2","price":"425"}
{"id":"3","product_name":"prod3","price":"375"}
...
]
```

My question is : can I get the product price from my jquery/template:  `'product_list_tmpl'` even I didn't use it in it?

Comment: You can iterate and get data from `jsonData` based of `product_name` i.e. value of radio

Comment: yes I can do that